# CSS mouse hover flickering issue

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

I'm new to CSS and I'm facing a problem. When the mouse moves over the input box, I want the text behind it to change color. But when the mouse moves over on it, flickering occurs.

How can I resolve the flickering without changing the following HTML structure?

```css
.back:hover {
  color: red;
}

.my-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 30px;
}

.my-input:hover {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.my-input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="back">
    Some text to be hovered even if input is above
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="my-input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dgknca I solved my problem with the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59569734/5110273). Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pointer-events: none` was only being applied while you were hovering over `.my-input`, and so the style was competing with it's own event. This style should be applied to the element by default

```css
.back:hover {
  color: red;
}

.my-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 30px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.my-input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="back">
    Some text to be hovered even if input is above
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="my-input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**From Comment:** If you're using jQuery, you can remove the `pointer-events: none`, as well as the `:hover` code, and keep the input intractable while still coloring the text

```js
$('.my-input').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.back').css('color', 'red');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.back').css('color', '');
  }
});
```

```css
.my-input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  opacity: 0.7;
  height: 30px;
}

.my-input:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="back">
    Some text to be hovered even if input is above
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" class="my-input" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question, I would be very glad if you answer. Can there be a solution in which the click event of the input is not disabled? With jQuery or JavaScript.

Comment: @developersdevelopers. I've updated the answer with this request

Answer (score 1):

In hover, using `pointer-event: none` is a complete opposite. In the case of `pointer-event: none`, hover cannot be captured. When hover is used, `pointer-event: none` is valid, which destroys the hover state. Therefore, the use of "pointer-event: none" when hovering over the mouse is extremely opposite and incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Adding my 2 cents here. I had a `card` for Bootstrap 5.1.3 and ran into similar situation. Following worked for me:

```
.card { 
  transition: all .3s ease; 
}
.card:hover { 
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.9;
  transition: opacity .3s;
}
```

Using above fixed the nasty flickering on hover on the `card` for me.